# How to encrypt keys in a content-addressable store, for lookup and enumeration

Tags: encryption, protocol-design, initialization-vector

I'm implementing a content-addressable file store - similar to a key/value store, but the key is always a hash of the value.

I'd like to build an encryption layer for it, to hide what data is being stored on the server device. Encrypting the data is easy and doesn't need anything special - it'd be just like encrypting a file. However, I'd like to encrypt the keys as well (I'll call these the "lookup keys", to differentiate them from the encryption keys), so that the server cannot prove I have some piece of data by just comparing the hash.

Problem is, the keys need to have two properties to make the key/value store work:

1. The encrypted lookup key needs to be computable from the plaintext lookup key and the secret encryption key, and nothing else.
2. The encrypted lookup key needs to be decryptable, so that the client can enumerate files from the server.

Similar question on this site like [encrypted lookup-keys for key-value store](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66187/encrypted-lookup-keys-for-key-value-store) say to use the HMAC of the plaintext lookup key, but that doesn't allow for decryption.

The main problem for simply encrypting the lookup keys is that I'm not able to use an IV, since the client won't have it before it does the lookup. As far as I can tell, I don't need it for integrity (It's a hash of the plaintext value, so its straightforward to validate, or alternatively I can store an HMAC along the value) or for protection from replay attacks (worst that could happen is that an attacker can re-insert some data), but for most encryption modes, reusing the IV can leak info about part of the plaintext, which I'd like to avoid. There may be other issues as well that I have not found.

I could potentially generate an IV by computing the HMAC of the plaintext lookup hash and using it as the IV, but there may be problems with that.

Are there any good solutions to this? Or at the very least, issues with my findings above that I have not seen?

Comment: Some more research: I think the SIV cypher mode will do what I need.

Comment: Can't you just use HMAC (plaintext, encryption key) to derive the plaintext lookup key? Then the server can't correlate that MAC with any plaintext without knowledge of your key.

Comment: @knaccc I need to be able to enumerate keys on the server and decrypt them back into their plaintext versions, so that rules out HMACs.

Comment: But if the plaintext lookup key is defined as HMAC (plaintext, encryption key), you don't need to decrypt it. Is there a reason you can't use the HMAC output as the only key for lookup of a plaintext? The only reason I can think of is if you want to be able to check for the existence of the same plaintext in multiple places, where in each place the plaintext and the corresponding lookup keys have been encrypted/derived with different encryption keys.

Comment: @knaccc Right. The upper levels of the content addressed store deal with the plain hash of the data, potentially from different servers with different keys, and aren't equipped to hmac the plaintext

Comment: If you need to download the list of keys from the server and the compare with your own list of plaintext hashes, can you do this: 1. Base the encrypted key on HMAC(plaintext hash, encryption key) instead of on HMAC(plaintext, encryption key) 2. Transform your own list of plaintext hashes into encrypted hashes prior to the comparison? Hash operations are very cheap to compute

Comment: @knaccc No. Again, I need to enumerate the entries on the server, without the client knowing what plaintext keys will be on the server.

Comment: Could you explain what "enumerate entries on the server" means? I thought you meant you wanted the server to send all keys to the client, so the client can see which of its plaintexts are stored on the server.